# Spring AOP configured with XML doesn't work

Tags: xml, spring, spring-aop

I'm trying to create a Spring AOP program configured with XML.

But i got an error:

*Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'performanceImpl' defined in class path resource [concert/concertConfig.xml]: BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJPointcutAdvisor#0': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#7cbd213e' of type [org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJMethodBeforeAdvice] while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#7cbd213e': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'performance' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'performance': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/weaver/reflect/ReflectionWorld$ReflectionWorldException*

Looks like it couldn't create the Bean 'performanceImpl', i've checked my code a lot of times, but still have no idea about it. Wish someone could find the problem.

This is my code:

```
    package concert;
    public interface Performance {
        public void perform();
    }

    package concert;
    public class PerformanceImpl implements Performance {
        @Override
        public void perform() {
            System.out.println("Performing now!");
        }
    }
```

**Aspect**

```
package concert;
public class Audience{
public void silencePhone() {
    System.out.println("Silencing phone please!");
}

public void takeSeats() {
    System.out.println("Taking seats please!");
}

public void clap() {
    System.out.println("CLAP CLAP CLAP!");
}

public void demandRefund() {
    System.out.println("You can demand the refund.");
}
}
```

**XML file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<bean id="performanceImpl" class="concert.PerformanceImpl"></bean>
<bean id="audience" class="concert.Audience"></bean>

<aop:config>
    <aop:aspect ref="audience">
        <aop:pointcut id="performance"
            expression="execution(** concert.Performance.perform(..))"/>

        <aop:before pointcut-ref="performance"
            method="silencePhone"/>

        <aop:before pointcut-ref="performance"
            method="takeSeats"/>

        <aop:after pointcut-ref="performance"
            method="clap"/>

        <aop:after-throwing pointcut-ref="performance"
            method="demandRefund"/>
    </aop:aspect>
</aop:config>

</beans>
```

**JUnitTest**

```
package concert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
public class ConcertTest {
@Test
public void test() {
    ApplicationContext cpx = new 
    ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("concert/concertConfig.xml");
    Performance performance = cpx.getBean("performanceImpl",
    PerformanceImpl.class);
    performance.perform();
}
}
```

Comment: The `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/weaver/reflect/ReflectionWorld$ReflectionWorldException` looks pretty clear to me. You are missing a jar on your class path.

Comment: thanks!  i did miss aspectj-1.8.10.jar, aspectjweaver-1.8.10.jar and aopalliance-1.0.jar... It runs pretty well now.

Comment: Plus i met a new problem after i add those three jars on my class path. The error: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: Bean named 'eddie' must be of type [com.springinaction.Instrumentalist], but was actually of type [$Proxy4]

Comment: then i replaced cpx.getBean("performanceImpl",PerformanceImpl.class) in my JunitTest with cpx.getBean("performanceImpl",Performance.class), then it works! lol, i read this link, it's really helpful! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3590512/beannotofrequiredtypeexception-with-spring-aop?rq=1

Comment: I would suggest you not to use cumbersome XML approach for AOP integration in Spring when we already have Annotations for the same.
Try checking this out for getting a gist.

http://codemodeweb.blogspot.in/2018/03/spring-aop-and-aspectj-framework.html

Answer (score 0):

If you see the error message you will see:

```
Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/weaver/reflect/ReflectionWorld$ReflectionWorldException
```

and that is because you did not add needed libraries into your project.
If you are using maven in your project you need to add at least these dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

considering the versions:

```
<properties>
    <spring.version>5.2.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <aspectj.version>1.9.5</aspectj.version>
</properties>
```